# How to restore mysql database schemas with its data in ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Accedednlty
one of my employees ran a script into the production server instead of the development server.
so he dropped 7 columns with its data.

i everyday backup all my server files into another server so I should have all the data,

is there any way to retrieve the whole database changes?

where are the mysql schemas and its data saved? i tried to copy and paste the ibd files but it didn't help

Note that my backupserver is cloning  the whole server as is.

Please anyone can help me ?

Comment: what do you mean by database changes, since the backup no and tell you employee in his SOP first always make a backup and check that it is ok

Comment: database changes means coloums drops 
i have all my server data in another server 
so im asking if there is  a way to get the database back

Comment: you have to use a second server or a separate database, depending how you make  your backup and copy the data from the recobvered server

Comment: if you can help me where are the stored files ? 
where can i find .frm i found the ibd files already 
but when i get them back only the IBD
 it says table name space is missing

Comment: Do not restore file by file. Start a new database instance up on a copy of your backed up data directory. Take a logical mysqldump of the table that was changed. Then restore that. Search other questions here on restoration, there is advice on how to do backups and restores correctly. You aren't the first person to naively approach this problem.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi by default you find all files in `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: @nbk thanks for trying helping me i already found the ibd files but when i replaced them it shows me tablespace is missing

Comment: You're not going to solve it by just directly copying the `.ibd` files from the backup into the production server database folder. It's possible but is not advisable and highly dependant on your database config from the beginning. For example, if you don't have `innodb_file_per_table=ON`, then the restoration option of copying `.ibd` files directly to folder (+other steps) will never work. Other than that, there are  "safer" ways to restore the table and it's data instructions on stackexchange site.

Comment: For mysql it doesn't matter which files are in the data directoryx as long as they fit. the error message tells you that you **didn't copy all files** the emphasis is on **all**